# Android listview toggle button

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, simplecursoradapter

I have a `Listview` that will  list the alarms which are in the database.I need to add a `Toggle` Button beside each  list item to set the alarm on/off.

How can I add the `Toggle` Button in the `ListView`?

`R.layout.alarm_list`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_reminders"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
      private void fillData() {
    Cursor remindersCursor = aDbHelper.fetchAllAlarms();
    startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list
    // (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[] { AlarmDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this
    // case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.alarm_row, remindersCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(reminders);
   }
```

`R.layout.alarm_row`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:padding="10dip" android:layout_width="242dp"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

My project is getting delayed.

Help

Comment: i tried adding the toggle button in R.layout.alarm_row..But it gives error.

Comment: Check this: [Android - How to create custom listview?](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&cp=24&gs_id=3b&xhr=t&q=android+custom+listview+example&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&biw=1333&bih=666&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=android+custom+listview+&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=105f40160a393e37)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no small snippet ans. to your problem. I assume you need to have multi-selection. Now here are the things you need.

Since you are using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you should replace that with `CursorAdapter`. To do so you have to extend it as it is a abstract adapter. Once you done that you will be overriding two functions.

- `newView` Where you will create your list item views by inflating `R.layout.alarm_row` (it should contain your toggle button too). You have make toggle button non-clickable.
- `bindView` where you will set state of toggle button and text for your text view

That said this what you need on the Activity side.

- You have make your ListView to multi-selection mode by `android:choiceMode` in xml or using `setChoiceMode`.

Now `bindView` will look like:

```
ListView lv = ((ListActivity)context).getListView();
// Containing all check states
SparseBooleanArray sba = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();


// I am using check box

cb.setChecked(false);

// Cursor is passed as an argument.
if(sba != null)
  if(sba.get(cursor.getPosition()))
     cb.setChecked(true);
```

Ref to docs:

[CursorAdapter docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom adapter like:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

and a custom layout for the rows with a toggle button (you will have to inflate the layout in the method geView).

Here you can find an example: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Hope this helps..

Comment: I have changed the second layout file (R.layout.alarm_row) as shown below..After doing this i cant set onclick listener for rows which is created.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/text1" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_width="242dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/toggleButton1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>